# unsure of fseek syntax in c

Tags: c, fseek

I was just wondering with this code why you have to start reading at 1 place before the end in `fseek(fptr, -1, SEEK_END);` and why you have to go back 2 places instead of 1 in `fseek(fptr, -2, SEEK_CUR);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE * fptr;

int main()
{
    char letter;
    int i;

    fptr = fopen("/Users/Dan/Documents/Coding/alpbkw/alphabet.txt", "w+");

    if (fptr == 0)
    {
        printf("there was an error opening the file");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++) //knows how to count up the alphabet
    {
        fputc(letter,fptr); //note syntax. fputc puts characters in a file
    }

    puts("characters have been written in the file");

    fseek(fptr, -1, SEEK_END); //looks in fptr, starts from 1 byte before the end. the -1 is the offset. this statement shows where it starts, not how it cycles. i think end of file doesnt actually have a letter printed on it, its a placeholder or something
    printf("here is the file backwards\n");

    for (i=26;i>0;i--) //starting from the last and counting backwards. goes through 26 times as expects 26 letters
    {
        letter = fgetc(fptr); //gets the letter it is currently on and reads it
        fseek(fptr, -2, SEEK_CUR); //backs up 2 places, if back up twice you will only print z's.
        printf("the next letter is %c.\n", letter);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you are at position X in the file, then you read one character which moves the position to position X+1, then you want to go to the character before X which is position X-1. How much do you need to seek to go from position X+1 to position X-1? You need to seek -2 positions.

Comment: ohhh so when you read you move the cursor across what you are reading. thanks for that!

Comment: And if you're still wondering about the first question: `fseek( fptr, 0, SEEK_END)` will put the pointer _just beyond_ the last character of the file, so you need `fseek( fptr, -1, SEEK_END)` to be in the right position to read the last character.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of `fseek()` calls along with `fgetc()` and/or small `fread()` calls, you're probably better off disabling buffering with `setbuf()` or `setvbuf()`; or using `open()`, `lseek()` and `read()` or just `pread()`.  `FILE *`-based IO by default is buffered, and the buffer size is usually something like 8KB.  But `fseek()` will invalidate the buffer, causing your next small `fread()` or `fgetc()` (a one-byte read) to be very likely to read an entire 8KB - again and again.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point, but just to balance it: if the file is (or is usually) relatively small, such that (most of) it fits inside said buffer, sticking to the buffered functions may be better as the `fseek()`s should just reposition a pointer within the buffer.

Comment: @TripeHound - True, but If the entire file can fit into a normal `FILE *` buffer, I'd venture to say you're likely to be better off just reading it into a `char[]` and accessing the bytes directly.  But then again I'm not a big fan of using the stdio set of `FILE *` based IO routines when performance really matters.  Given most OSes have a page cache, the stdio buffer can easily get redundant and actually slow things down.  In most cases, though, the best code is code that the developers working on it recognize and understand.